# How to remove "Restore Previous Versions" Context Menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, contextmenu

Windows 10 is showing a "Restore previous version" context menu entry.

### How to remove this context menu entry?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Delete these 4 registry keys.** Preferably in a `cmd` window with admin privileges:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}" /f
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}" /f
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}" /f
REG DELETE "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}" /f
```

By the way, the fastest way to open a `cmd` with admin rights is:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>
2. Type `cmd`
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shirt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Execute all 4 commands in there.

> ⚠ **Caution:** If you don't need the restore function at all, just disable it. It will save you some resources.

Answer (score 0):

Click Win+R

Write regedit.exe

Navigate to this path in regedit

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked.

Now, switch to the right-pane and create a new string value –

{596AB062-B4D2-4215-9F74-E9109B0A8153}

keep the second value from that window empty take a look on the reference website for more clarification

That's it

Reference Link